# How to copy params from one LinearLayout and set to another LinearLayout in code?

Tags: android, android-widget

How to copy params from one LinearLayout and set to another LinearLayout  in code ?
I have tried like

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsR=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) llRight.getLayoutParams();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsL=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) llLeft.getLayoutParams();
paramsR.height=paramsL.height;
paramsR.width=paramsL.width;
llRight.setLayoutParams(paramsR);
```

but it ignores at all. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score -4):

If the parent of `llRight` & `llLeft` is `RelativeLayout` then you should use:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsR=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) llRight.getLayoutParams();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsL=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) llLeft.getLayoutParams();
paramsR.height=paramsL.height;
paramsR.width=paramsL.width;
llRight.setLayoutParams(paramsR);
```